# Spacing in footnote

Tags: latex, spacing

I am trying to write my affiliation and I need to use multiple lines. What I do is

```
\author{Me
    \footnote{First line
         \newline  Second line}}
```

But in the footnotes this appears as [image: link]

How do I make second line appear directly below first line? Specifically I would like it if `S` was exactly below `F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a space to the exact width of the footnote mark - `1.8em`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{Me\footnote{First line \newline
  \hspace*{1.8em}Second line}%
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```